# rewrite rule for changing url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the rewrite rule for changing the url if an user types

```
http://localhost/website/cool
```

Then it should be changed to

```
http://localhost/website/save.php?id=cool
```

Comment: just tell the one line answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, can't format code in a commet. This is to answer the question:

> May you please tell me what is RewriteCond

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/save.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ save.php?id=$1
```

If the URI doesn't have /save.php in it, then it will rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ save.php?id=$1
```

Comment: hey,This $1 is printing save.php not the given value

Comment: Then debug. What URL do you use, what's in your PHP file, what do you see in your browser, what do you expect.

Comment: $1 doesn't print anything, it's a string. Strings don't print. Please answer my questions or I can't help you.

Comment: i mean this <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> is printing save.php in page "save.php" which is not expected

Comment: Please just update your question with full info (php code, URL used, what you see in your browser) since it won't fit in comments and other people might find it useful.

Comment: It's because the RewriteEngine doesn't stop until the rewritten path is the same as the original path, so it goes through twice, first time it rewrites to save.php?id=something, then it goes through again and rewrites to save.php?id=save.php, sees that both target and path are same and stops. You need a RewriteCond to prevent rewriting if the URI starts with `/save.php`

Comment: what is go in last comment    ?

Comment: Mr. Jon lin May you please tell me what is RewriteCond

Comment: @AnkitGautam Have a look at the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond